# Rearranging Arrays in Excel

Tags: excel

I am working on a tool to give to another user so they can enter the number of required heads per production line and Excel will spit out a schedule for someone to cover the workers while they go on break. The schedule is just a column showing, by time period, either a line assignment or a break.

For instance, if I have five workers on production lines, then I need to give five breaks. The person covering the breaks must also have a break. Assuming a break is 10 minutes long, I now need to schedule six 10 minute intervals where five will be occupied with work and one will be a break.

- Scenario 1: All workers are covering Line19 so five intervals will show "Line19" and one will show "Break" - the break will be in one of the middle cells. (Line19, Line19, Line19, Break, Line19, Line19)
- Scenario 2: Half of the breaks are on Line19 and half of the breaks are on Line20. I want to group the line assignments by type and automatically place the break time between the assignments. (Line19, Line19, Line19, Break, Line20, Line20 or Line19, Line19, Break, Line20, Line20, Line20)
- Scenario 3: When three or more lines are being scheduled, place the break after the second change in line. (Line19, Line19, Line20, Break, Line21, Line21)

The number of intervals to be scheduled will not change but the number of line assignments will be dynamic according to the number of heads (also dynamic).

I have worked out the logic for everything except how to sort these intervals automatically.   Right now my execution is as simple as all values in a column with each row being an assignment needing coverage (20 heads will generate 20 rows). I have left blanks in the column as placeholders for breaks and this is why I need the resort.

```
-Before-                -After- (in another column)
Line19                  Line19
Line19                  Line19
Line20                  Line20
(empty - no formula)    Line20
Line20                  Line20
Line20                  Break
Line21                  Line21
Line21                  Line21
Line21                  Line21
```

Any ideas? I'm not as well versed with VBA/Macros as I should be but they are an option with the understanding that, once built, another user will be in control of the file.

Comment: Can you give us a better idea of what the inputs would be?

Comment: The user has a "summary" page where there is a list of production lines and they enter the required heads for each line. There is another sheet where the calculations happen, ending with a table that takes those requirements (3 heads on Line19 = 3 rows of "Line19", 4 heads on Line20 = 4 rows of "Line20", etc...) and generates the list shown above as "Before."